# What is a seamless way to migrate a user profile in vista?

Tags: windows-vista, workgroup

What is the best way to migrate a user profile in Vista?  I just tried the Vista Easy Transfer and found that it did not do everything I wanted it to do.  I am trying to leave a leave a domain and join a workgroup.

Comment: Somewhat related to http://serverfault.com/questions/76713/

Comment: Vista is acting somewhat differently.

Comment: Care to elaborate on what is not working?  Or what you are expecting it to do?

Comment: Sorry, I was quite vaugue earlier.  I'm attempting to leave a domain and join a workgroup.  Ideally I would like it to be transfer to be invisible to my user, this involves migrating the profile, but I'm really not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote about [how to migrate a profile on my blog](http://blog.stronico.com/2009/11/how-to-migrate-user-profile-in-vista.html), (as well as why I was trying to do it) but the short, practical answer is to just download the user profile wizard from Forensit and use that.  I tried many other methods, but could not find any other good way of getting the job done.

Answer (score 0):

I know that Windows7  has a built-in backup feature that will backup and/or restore your user profile.